# Implement this chart in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, charts, react-native-svg-charts

In the following chart:

[image: Chart Image]

The white spot moves along the black line.
I can make background bars, but curve live and white spot seems difficult.

I already use [react-native-svg-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-charts) for other charts but IDK that I can make this chart with this library.

How shall I implement this chart in react native?

Comment: `I can make background bars` = which is the code you're using to draw the chart? - it is difficult to check without seeing the data or how the chart is built.

Comment: data is 1to10 in both the y-axis and x-axis. And only white spot move along the black curve line base on the value of y-axis and x-axis